# Cannot find 2D option in unity Universal RP Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, post-processing, urp

I created a URP project in Unity 2020.3.6 and , I was thinking to create pong game with some URP effects, but i cannot find 2D option in hierarchy or Game Object tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjcvG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPWnV.png)

And When i Make a 2D project and add URP package and post processing package to it, then camera is not showing post processing option,

can any one tell where can i find 2D object options that usually show in other version of unity even in 3rd or URP projects.

and yes these 2d Light feature is also dissabled i cannot select any one :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26owq.png)

Comment: Have you set the URP asset to use [2D Renderer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-renderer-in-universal-render-pipeline-in-2019-3.829851/) ?

Comment: yes Now i have set up every thing, the thing that was missing was adding pipeline in graphics tab in player setting, now eveything is working fine